# jQuery find() not working with prev()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm probably doing it the wrong way so that is why I need your help.
I have set up a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/m35o8jjL/2/

HTML:

```js
$( ".layered_subtitle_heading" ).click(function() {
  $(this).prev().find('.layered_close').toggleClass('closed');
  $(this).prev().find('.layered_filter_ul').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layered_filter">
  <div class="layered_subtitle_heading clearfix">
    <span class="layered_subtitle">Metall</span> 
    <span class="layered_close"> <a href="javascript:;" data-rel="ul_layered_id_feature_9"></a> </span>
  </div>
  <ul id="ul_layered_id_feature_9" class="layered_filter_ul ">
    <li class="nomargin hiddable filter_lg">
      <div class="checker" id="uniform-layered_id_feature_38">
        <span>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </span>
      </div>
      <label for="layered_id_feature_38">
        <a href="#">925  Sterling Silber</a> 
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Basically , what I want is when user clicks on the `layered_subtitle_heading` div, class toggles of the `layered_close span` , same with the display of the `ul`.

I'm probably not using `prev()` correctly but I really can't think of any way to make this work.

I have multiple `layered_filters` and that is why I have to use `$(this)`.

Comment: using $(this).parent() will return <div class="layered_filter">

Comment: Just use closest() it might help you.

Comment: @GiorgiJambazishvili still nothing when clicking the heading

Comment: you're listening to `click` on `$( ".layered_subtitle_heading" )`?

Comment: Keep your browser console open so you can see errors, such as the ones your fiddle was getting because jQuery was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix it remove .prev() and add .siblings() to get the ul to toggle

```
 $( ".layered_subtitle_heading" ).click(function() {
     $(this).find('.layered_close').toggleClass('closed');
     $(this).siblings('.layered_filter_ul').toggle();
     // you need to use alert()
     alert('da');
 });
```

and you hadn't added jQuery to your fiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Miraidev/m35o8jjL/13/

Comment: Other options that work are the ones @Pointy suggested and .next()

Answer (score 1):

The `.prev()` method is for navigating to the previous **sibling**. Your target `<div>` does not have a previous sibling; it's the first child of its parent.

What you probably want to do instead is

```
$(this).parent().find('.layered_close').toggleClass('closed');
```

or, to be a little more resilient to change:

```
$(this).closest(".layered_filter").find('.layered_close').toggleClass('closed');
```

Comment: Have you tried your answer in the jsfiddle? both of these suggestions arent working.

Comment: @fegiar your jsfiddle doesn't work because you didn't configure it to import jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $( ".layered_subtitle_heading" ).click(function() {
          $(this).parent().toggleClass('closed');
      });
  });
```